# Thermodynamics: Is an adiabatic change of liquid water isochor?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was studying mechanical engineering and I am currently learning thermodynamics.

I've got a simple circular process that looks like this:
[image]

Furthermore, I've given the following data:

$ t_1 = 60 C $

$ p_2 = 10 MPa $   $ p_2 = 600 C $

$ p_3 = 15 kPa $   $ x_3 = 0.848 $

$ x_4 = 0 $

Furthermore the process from $1$ to $2$ is isobar.
The turbine is adiabatic, the condensator is isobar and the pump is also adiabatic.

Now my task is to draw this process into an pV-Diagramm and there is something that I do not understand.

It is clear that every isobar process is simply a horizontal line.
However the solution states that the process from $4$ to $1$ is not only adiabatic but also isochor. Why is that?

> Is an adiabatic change of liquid water always isochor?

Comment: It's an isochor if liquid water is regarded as incompressible.  If you are using steam tables to analyze the system, then the steam tables will also include the small effect of the compressibility of water.  it's not going to be significant, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate how small the change in specific volume is during the adiabatic compression, process look at the data for the change in specific volume between points (4) and (1).

The pressure at the end of the condensation process $P_4$ (saturated water) is the same as the pressure at the beginning of the condensation process $P_3$ (saturated vapor), that is,

$$P_4 = P_3= 15KPa$$

From the saturated steam table, the specific volume at point 4 is

$$v_4≈ 0.00104 \frac{m^3}{kg}$$

Now looking at point (1), the pressure there is the same as point (2) therefore

$$P_1 = P_2 = 10MPa$$

And you have given the temperature at $P_1$ as $60 C$

We can find the specific volume of compressed liquid water at $60 C$ and $10MPa$ from a compressed liquid water properties table (e.g., Ohio.edu) which gives us

$$v_1 = 0.0010126 \frac{m^3}{kg}$$

The difference in specific volume from points 4 and 1 is about 2.6%. I think we can consider this small enough to call it an isochoric process.

Hope this helps.